# Oracle procedure variable is not yet denotable

Tags: oracle, common-table-expression, procedure, default-value

I have a procedure that takes in a start_date. I'm trying to modify the procedure to set a default end_date based on the start_date if an end_date isn't passed into the procedure. I'm getting an error (see below).

Errors: PROCEDURE XXX
Line/Col: 0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis terminated
Line/Col: 4/35 PLS-00227: subprogram 'in' formal I_START_DATE is not yet denotable

Is there a way to get around this problem? Below is my TEST CASE, which also produces the error. I'm testing on live SQL so our environments can be the same.

Thanks in advance for your expertise and to all who answer.

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'MMDDYYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Create table employees(
          employee_id NUMBER(6), 
          first_name VARCHAR2(20),
          last_name VARCHAR2(20),
         card_num VARCHAR2(10),
          work_days VARCHAR2(7)
       );

ALTER TABLE employees
        ADD (
          CONSTRAINT employees_pk PRIMARY KEY (employee_id)
              );

        INSERT INTO employees (
         employee_id,
         first_name, 
         last_name,
         card_num,
         work_days
        )
        WITH names AS   ( 
          SELECT 1, 'John',     'Doe',      'D564311','YYYYYNN' FROM dual UNION ALL
          SELECT 2, 'Justin',     'Case',      'C224311','YYYYYNN' FROM dual UNION ALL
        SELECT 3, 'Mike',     'Jones',      'J288811','YYYYYNN' FROM dual UNION ALL
         SELECT 4, 'Jane',     'Smith',      'S564661','YYYYYNN' FROM dual 
       ) SELECT * FROM names; 


    CREATE TABLE locations AS
    SELECT level AS location_id,
       'Door ' || level AS location_name,

    CASE round(dbms_random.value(1,3)) 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'A' 
            WHEN 2 THEN 'T' 
            WHEN 3 THEN 'T' 
         END AS location_type

    FROM   dual
    CONNECT BY level <= 5;


     ALTER TABLE locations 
         ADD ( CONSTRAINT locations_pk
       PRIMARY KEY (location_id));

create table access_history(
      seq_num integer  GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1) NOT NULL,
       employee_id NUMBER(6), 
       card_num varchar2(10),
       location_id number(4),
       access_date date,
       processed NUMBER(1) default 0
    );


create or replace procedure xxx (
  i_start_date in date,
 
 i_end_date IN DATE DEFAULT TRUNC(i_start_date) + 1, 

 i_interval         IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10
) as
BEGIN

INSERT INTO access_history (employee_id, card_num, location_id, access_date)
WITH date_rows ( start_date, end_date ) AS (
 SELECT i_start_date,
                i_end_date
 FROM   DUAL
UNION ALL
 SELECT start_date + 
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_interval, 'MINUTE'),
        end_date
 FROM   date_rows
 WHERE  start_date +
NUMTODSINTERVAL(i_interval, 'MINUTE') < end_date
)
SELECT     e.employee_id
,        e.card_num
,       l.location_id
,       d.start_date
FROM       employees e
CROSS JOIN locations l
CROSS JOIN date_rows d;
END;
/


EXEC xxx(timestamp '2021-08-21 22:37:12');
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign a parameter a default value based on another parameter from within the procedure specification.

Do your definition as follows:

```
create or replace procedure xxx (
  i_start_date in date,
  i_end_date IN DATE default null, 
  i_interval         IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10
) as
  l_end_date date := nvl(i_end_date, TRUNC(i_start_date) + 1);
begin
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Did you test your solution?

EXEC XXX
(timestamp '2021-08-21 20:37:12', NULL);

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XXX'

Comment: @beefstu the first 2 arguments in your call do not match the procedure specification. Try `exec xxx(sysdate, sysdate, null);` In your example the first argument is a timestamp, the second is varchar2 (both are not dates).

Answer (score 0):

The most obvious workaround is to use some dummy value as the default, and then replace it in the body of the procedure. The most obvious choice for the dummy value is NULL.  For example:

```
create or replace procedure xxx (
  i_start_date in date, 
  i_end_date IN DATE DEFAULT NULL, 
  i_interval         IN PLS_INTEGER DEFAULT 10
)
AS
  l_end_date  DATE;
BEGIN
  IF i_end_date IS NULL THEN
    l_end_date := TRUNC(i_start_date) + 1;
  END IF;
  ...
END;
```

The question is whether NULL is a value that a caller might pass that is supposed to have a different meaning.  For instance, you may want NULL to mean there is no upper limit on the date.  In this case you could choose some specific date value as the dummy -- something that should never be passed as a meaningful value, like '01-JAN-1800'.

Comment: Did you test your solution?

EXEC XXX
(timestamp '2021-08-21 20:37:12', NULL);

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'XXX'

Comment: @Beefstu.  I hadn't, but I just did, and your call works without errors for me.  Although I did catch a syntax error in my code (DECLARE keyword was not needed).

Comment: my apologies it worked great!! When I cut and pasted I accidentally had a newline in the call, which I thought was a wrap around. There was 2 hours down the drain. Thanks again for your help. I'm a DBA who has been thrown SQL development projects. Ugggg